# How to access HTML files locally in an offline web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a mobile web based game. I want to use a single page design, and I want it to be able to run offline. I want to design and store the different HTML pages I would use as files in a folder, and just load them into my div whenever I need them. The problem is I cannot find a way to load local files using web technology.

The normal way is to host the files on a server, and fetch via AJAX etc but I want to bypass the fetch time and allow the app to run offline.

Right now what I'm doing is creating my html pages, storing them as strings in JS files and   using that, but I'm hoping there is a better solution.

Ideally I want something like `$(".mydiv").load("../html/login.html")`. However since load uses AJAX I don't think that will work.

EDIT: I am planning to use phone gap build to package my app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://sammyjs.org/ is a library that I started using which handles this problem perfectly. It allows you to separate HTML code and include it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Save all of your data inside the single web page, as invisible elements, then display them as needed. "Single-page design" is called that for a reason - you only get the one page. But that page can be arbitrarily large, you can modify it on the fly, and you can display and hide parts as suits you. You can also use any of the [clientside templating engines](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) to simulate your `.load()` as if you were loading it from a server.

**EDIT**: The fact that you're building a PhoneGap application completely changes matters (should've said so from the start): PhoneGap acts like a server, allowing you to build a multi-page application. Thus, everything (including `.load()` [should work as you expect](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=en). You can't *test* your application without a web-server, because just opening a file from your hard disk (i.e. using `file:` protocol) does not allow it, so for testing you will have to move to a web server. However, "single-page design" in your question is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Wouldn't all of these elements that I am hiding take resources? I was under the impression that they ARE loaded but not visible, so if there are enough it will cause problems. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong, they do take resources; but a ten or a hundred widgets' worth of HTML is not at all huge. If it's data you want and not simply UI, then you should use a database (see HTML5 storage for key/value store, and WebSQL if you need more than that - but the latter doesn't work on IE and Firefox at the moment). Or just stick it into the page nevertheless, unless your data is really really huge.

Comment: Keep in mind this app is intended for mobile devices, (phones and tablets) so performance is more of an issue than on desktop. Right now I believe this solution (everything in one page) is what I will use, and hope that I find an alternative before it becomes a bottle-neck. Thanks!

Comment: So you are saying that I can .load local files using phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my suggestion is relevant, but if you use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) you could build a standalone mobile application using your standard web technologies. Perhaps you could check it out...

Comment: This is what I am doing! However it doesn't resolve the local files problem. I could build plugins for every OS to connect JS functions to Objective-C or Java and use the native languages to do the file i/o. Seems not worth though

Comment: You're using PhoneGap!?! Added more info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do this and a hard way...you're going down the hard path...

I built a single page html5 mobile app which controls a credit card reader via javascript. The card reader does require an internet connection.  The other portions are quite easy to work in an offline mode.

The easy way to do this is with the help of a good mobile framework.  In particular you need a framework which makes it easy to work offline.

As there are lots of frameworks, choose one that has an offline component.   The framework which I used is Dhtmlx Touch  http://dhtmlx.com/touch.  Choose a framework which creates the page 100% from a json string--NOT divs.  Then it is quite easy, you can store the pages in the browser's local storage as json objects.

So you have 1 html5 page...a good javascript framework...and local storage.

Dhtmlx Touch has an offline component built into the framework: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/touch/doku.php?id=how_to_create_offline_apps

With the right tools, it's all quite easy....and it works fine with PhoneGap or a Native Webview.